# Setting wordwrap width in a Textbox VB Dot Net Visual Basic

Tags: textbox, width, word-wrap

How can I set a text box to wordwrap with no more that 47 characters per line.

Textbox is set to multiline = true and wordwrap = true.
[I'm using a normal not rich textbox, but can use richtextbox if needed]

The textbox is populated via a button that pastes contents of the clipboard.
Before that though the user is selecting text in a different application (3rd party - not VB) that has a much bigger textbox width, and copying to clipboard.

I then need to be able to alter my text box so it wordwraps but with no more that 47 characters per line.

Once that's done I then want to be able to read 1 line at a time (should only be about 5 lines) and paste into clipboard - I can do that OK - but it's the 47 character width that is the problem at the moment.

Thanks in advance.